# option_groups_from_collection_for_select in single table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to group option-tags, but the groups and values are in the same table.
Lets say i have the model "Person" with the methods :age and :name and i want to group by age and list all names for the corresponding age. This would be something like:

```
option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@people, :name, :age, :id, :name, 1)
```

Obviously this does not work because :name is a single value. Is there a simple solution? Maybe by creating a method ":names" for Person, but how do i set the connection to :age?

-Bump (Noone an idea? Maybe i can just build a string with all those groups and options?)

Answer (score 0):

I think your are missing the `group_label_method` parameter of the `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` method as shown [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select).

Try:

```
option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@people, :name, :name, :age, :id, :name, 1)
```

Comment: Then i get `wrong number of arguments (7 for 6)`.

Following the syntax from your link `collection` would be `@people.collect(&:age).uniq`. But how do i refer to a method from this collection?